# MMProgressHUD to show only notification

Tags: ios

Is it possible to make `MMProgressHUD` to show only notification with success/error icon instead of progress? I see that I can dismiss progress with success/error, but can't figure out if possible to initially show success/error.

Comment: Have a look at `SVProgressHUD`!

Comment: Sorry, my question is about `MMProgressHUD` because it has iOS 6 support. I am aware of `SVProgressHUD `.

Comment: Ok! It was only a comment anyway :)

Comment: You can use an image view with icon you want (success/error) and use it as the custom view `forMBProgressHUD`